# MySQL saves tables names as lower case

Tags: php, mysql

Is it the normal behaviour of MySQL to save table names as lowercase even when I create the tables with [CamelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) names? If it is not then how can I make it save the names as CamelCase?

**Edit:** I am using [XAMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP) on a machine running Windows 7. Is it a good idea to allow case sensitiive table names? What are the advantages and disadvantages?

Answer (score 3):

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html:

From the docs:

> In MySQL, databases correspond to
>   directories within the data directory.
>   Each table within a database
>   corresponds to at least one file
>   within the database directory (and
>   possibly more, depending on the
>   storage engine). Consequently, the
>   case sensitivity of the underlying
>   operating system plays a part in the
>   case sensitivity of database and table
>   names. This means database and table
>   names are not case sensitive in
>   Windows, and case sensitive in most
>   varieties of Unix. One notable
>   exception is Mac OS X, which is
>   Unix-based but uses a default file
>   system type (HFS+) that is not case
>   sensitive. However, Mac OS X also
>   supports UFS volumes, which are case
>   sensitive just as on any Unix. See
>   Section 1.8.4, “MySQL Extensions to
>   Standard SQL”. The
>   lower_case_table_names system variable
>   also affects how the server handles
>   identifier case sensitivity, as
>   described later in this section.